# Extracting data from a picture to using Pytesseract

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm attempting to extract data from the picture below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBIZ4.jpg)

The problem is that my output is absolute nonsense. All I get is a bunch of letters and no numbers...

Here is the code.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

img_cv = cv2.imread('path_name')
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_resized = cv2.resize(img_cv,
                         (int(img_cv.shape[1] + (img_cv.shape[1] * .1)),
                          int(img_cv.shape[0] + (img_cv.shape[0] * .30))),
                         interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) 
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
```

I'm new to Pytesseract so any help would be great. Thanks!